# Memory leak while resizing UIImage in arc

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimage

I am resizing the **UIImages** with the following method

```
- (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image toSize:(CGSize)newSize forName:(NSString *)name {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    [_dictSmallImages setObject:newImage forKey:name];
    return newImage;
}
```

And in **UITableView**'s **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method i am using it like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row + 1] removeFromSuperview];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"img%d", indexPath.row + 1];
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(8, 5, 304, 190);

    UIImage *scaledImage = [_dictSmallImages objectForKey:imageName];
    if (![_dictSmallImages objectForKey:imageName]) {
        scaledImage = [self resizeImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] toSize:CGSizeMake(304, 190) forName:imageName];
    }

    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageRect];
    [imgView setTag:indexPath.row + 1];
    [imgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [imgView setImage:scaledImage];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];

    if ((lastIndexPath.row == 10 && indexPath.row == 0) || indexPath.row == lastIndexPath.row) {

        if (_delegate) {
            NSString *imgName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"img%d", indexPath.row + 1];
            [_delegate selectedText:imgName];
        }

        [imgView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor];
        [imgView.layer setBorderWidth:5.0f];
        [imgView setAlpha:1.0f];
        lastIndexPath = indexPath;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

But when I check the leaks via Profile the instruments show me a leak like
[image: Leak shown in Instruments]

Can anybody please let me know why this leak is there ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two main facts that you should be knowing about `-imageNamed:`, especially when you decided to work with it :

1. `-imageNamed:` returns an autoreleased image, which will be autoreleased at some time in the future.
2. `-imageNamed` also caches the image it returns. The cache is retaining the image.

If you do not release it, the cache will continue to retain the image until it releases it, for instance when a memory warning occurs. So when you get an image using imageNamed, it doesn't get deallocated, until the cache is purged.

If you don't want the images to be cached for any reason, you should use an alternative method of creating them, for instance, `-imageWithContentsOfFile:` doesn't cache the image.

You can expect the image object returned from `-imageWithContentsOfFile:` to be autoreleased and not cached and it will be deallocated at the end of the run loop.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation @Bhavin I should take care while reading the documentation, thanks once again